# Defining a function in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I want to declare a function in SQL SERVER, It is the beginning of my code, but I get this error: 'CREATE FUNCTION' must be the only statement in the batch.

```
CREATE FUNCTION FindingMobileOrTelephone ( @Number nchar(11) )
RETURNS nvarchar
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ItIsMobile nvarchar;
    DECLARE @ItIsTelephone nvarchar;
    RETURNS @ItIsMobile;
END;
```

what is the problem?!

Comment: Add `GO` before create

Comment: @NoDisplayName I did it but i still get errors

Comment: You may have some statement before Create, either remove that or use go just before create as @NoDisplayName suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

Last Statement Should be `RETURN` not `RETURNS`

```
CREATE FUNCTION FindingMobileOrTelephone ( @Number nchar(11) )
RETURNS nvarchar
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ItIsMobile nvarchar;
    DECLARE @ItIsTelephone nvarchar;
    RETURN (@ItIsMobile);
    ^

END
```

Comment: Although  this is an important notice, it is still not the answer to the OP's question

Comment: @KirillSlatin check his Above Comments :)

Comment: I mean it should be a comment the the OP in this case. People who will find this post will think this is the answer although it isn't.

Comment: @KirillSlatin yeah According to Error what your are saying is right !

Answer (score 1):

CREATE FUNCTION/TABLE should be the first statement in the script you're executing.

One option was already mentioned. Adding `GO` kind of splits the script into separate ones.

However, if you have this within `BEGIN` `END` block this won't work since you can't split this block with `GO`.
An option here is to wrap `CREATE` statment into a string literal and use [EXEC or sp_executesql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26821927/t-sql-exec-versus-sp-exec)

```
-- your script
EXEC('CREATE FUNCTION ... END')
```